# Need to generate unique users when I start load test for Sign up

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I need to create unique users with (firstname, lastname, email, password) values each time I run load test (Sign Up).

I have already an empty CSV set config with firstname, lastname, email, password values.
The problem is that Jmeter tries to create a new user with email that was used before.
My goal is to run a load test for 10.000 unique users that I need to generate.

Please help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below solution:

**1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor to your "Sign Up" request.**
[image]

**2. Add the following groovy code to the JSR223 PreProcessor for the 5 fields.**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils

// Get the current Thread Number and Iteration Count
def threadNumber = ctx.getThreadNum()
def iterationCount = ctx.getVariables().getIteration()

// Generate random data
def firstName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)
def lastName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)
def email = "${firstName}_${lastName}_${threadNumber}_${iterationCount}" + "@email.com"
def password = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8)
def confirmPassword = password

// Set variables to be used in the test
vars.put("P_FirstName", firstName)
vars.put("P_LastName", lastName)
vars.put("P_Email", email)
vars.put("P_Password", password)
vars.put("P_ConfirmPassword", confirmPassword)
```

[image]

**3. Add the variables' names in the POST request**
[image]

**4. Now, before every request, the PreProcessor will generate unique values for the respective fields. Example:**

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help!
It looks like the script works ok but it fails on the password step and I discovered strict rules for passwords:

Your Password must contain: 
- 8 characters or more 
- 1 uppercase character (A-Z) 
- 1 lowercase character (a-z) 
- 1 number (0 -9) 
- 1 special character (! @ # $ % ^ ? & * ( ) - _ + .) 

Is it possible to generate a password that will match the current requirements in your script? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, try this--> instead of adding "${P_Password}" in the password Value of the request, add "P@s${P_Password}". Similarly, replace the "${P_ConfirmPassword}" with "P@s${P_ConfirmPassword}". This way, you fulfill the basic requirement of creating password.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't "generate" anything, when you use CSV Data Set Config - it just **reads** the entries from the file and if it's empty - it will just send either empty values or variables placeholders in form of `${username}`.

You either need to pre-generate emails and stuff somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and write them to the CSV file or replace your variables with [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which will generate random/unique data on the fly like [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) or [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) or [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) or any combination of above.